# How to assert if any string in a list of strings is contained in the Actual string

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, mstest

I have the following strings:

```
       Actual       |   Expected
"The Actual String" | "The"
                    | "Actual"
                    | "String"
                    | "Other string"
                    |    ...
```

I need to create a method that will `Assert` that any of the `Expected` strings is contained in the actual string, something like this:

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod()
    {
        //Assertion Passed
        AssertContainsString("The Actual String", "The"); 

        //Assertion Passed
        AssertContainsString("The Actual String", "Something", "Actual"); 

        //Assertion Failed
        AssertContainsString("The Actual String", "Something", "Something Else"); 
    }

    public void AssertContainsString(string actual, params string[] expected)
    {

    }
}
```

I tried the `CollectionAssert.Contains` method but it didn't work. Is there a quick method I can use without iterating into the `expected` strings?

Comment: how about split actual string into words and then use `CollectionAssert.Contains`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It returns true if all the values of expected array is found in actual variable:

```
bool foundall = expected.Except(actual.Split(' ')).Count()==0;
```

Return true even if just one value is contained in the actual string:

```
bool ans = expected.Except(actual.Split(' ')).Count() != expected.Length;
```

Comment: Thank you, but none of your suggestions worked. Every time the result is 'false'.

Comment: @Schaliasos, it returns true if all the values of expected array is found in  actual variable. Do you want to return true if any of the string in expected is available in actual.

Comment: I want to return true even if just one value is contained in the actual string.

Comment: @Schaliasos, try my second option, it will do your job.

Answer (score 3):

I think it's possible to use this "StringAssert.Contains(actualString,containsubstring);" in all Framework .NET

Comment: Not only does this already have an accepted answer from a year ago, but the OP also indicated that `StringAssert.Contains` did not work in his or her case.

Answer (score 1):

An extension method for the string class?

```
    public static bool AnyIn(this string s, params string[] values)
    {
        return values.Any(x => s.Contains(x));
    }
```

callable in this way:

```
    string test = "The actual string";
    if(test.AnyIn("The") == true)   // success
    ...
    if(test.AnyIn("The", "actual", "string") == true)   // success
    ...
    if(test.AnyIn("The", "actual", "value") == true)   // success
    ...
    if(test.AnyIn("some", "value") == true)   // fail
```

or also

```
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(test.AnyIn("some", "value"), "No expected string found"); // fail
```

of course put the extension method inside a static class
Tried also in Visual Studio 2010 Console Application

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            string test = "The actual string";

            // Prints False
            bool result = test.AnyIn("other", "value");
            Console.WriteLine(result.ToString()); 

            // Prints True
            result = test.AnyIn("other", "The");
            Console.WriteLine(result.ToString()); 

            //  No Assert dialog here 
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(test.AnyIn("other", "The"), "No expected values found");

            //  Big Assert dialog here with message "No expected values found"
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(test.AnyIn("other", "The"), "No expected values found");

        }

    }

    static class ext
    {
        public static bool AnyIn(this string s, params string[] values)
        {
            return values.Any(x => s.Contains(x));
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT:

The problem with different case could be resolved changing the extension in this way

```
public static bool AllIn(this string s, params string[] values)     
{         
     return values.Any(x => s.IndexOf(x + " ", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0);     
}
```

but, to prevent false positives when one of expected strings is embedded inside the actual string you need to add a space at the end of the actual string

```
string test = "The actual string ";  // notice the extra space added at the end
```

Comment: But it fails when calling it like `test.AnyIn("other","The")`

Comment: @Schaliasos Uhm, no, really no, just tested with LinqPAD.

Comment: I am testing it with Visual Studio. it returns false if the 1st string in `values` is not contained in the `test`

Comment: @Schaliasos, At this point, just out of curiosity, I have tested also in VS2010 with a Console application and works as expected. Something is off here. Could you post your test code?

Comment: The 2nd way `System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert` is passing but if I try to assign the result into a variable it is false

Comment: @Schaliasos, oh well, I don't know, just updated my answer but I don't have your results.

Comment: I am sorry, I had copy/paste your code before you changed it and I had that `return values.All(x => s.Contains(x));` instead of `Any`. Thank you very much for being patient with me. It works fine, thank you.

Comment: @Schaliasos no problem. It's my fault because I had not understood your question at the beginning. Just as a side note. Have you noticed that every answer given fails if the string _case_ is different ("the" doesn't match "The")

Comment: Yes I noticed that. It is failing

Answer (score 1):

if you did

```
if (actual.Split(' ').Contains(expected)) return true;
```

but I think you would still need to iterate the expected's

```
foreach (string ex in expected)
{
    if (actual.Split(' ').Contains(ex)) return true;
}
```

**EDIT** as per Gene S comment

```
expected.Any(ex => actual.Split(' ').Contains(ex))
```

use the sugar if you want to, but there is no processor savings, it just makes it harder to read.

Comment: I assumed as much, but why would you want to avoid it.  Do you expect to have hundreds of objects to iterate through?  if there is a cleaner way of doing it, it will simply be a syntax sugar type thing.  From the computers point of view(processor), there is no way to compare things without iterating through them and comparing them

Comment: If you want the syntactical sugar you can do this...
"expected.Any(ex => actual.Split(' ').Contains(ex))"...but in the end the compiler will compile this down to a loop.

Comment: @K'Leg Well, I really thought it might exist a faster way than the `foreach` because I want to use in Load Testing where each unit test will call the method with many expected strings.

Comment: @GeneS That is what I was getting it doesn't matter how yuo tell the compiler to do it, it will iterate through it the same way.

Comment: @K'Leg Right, I was agreeing with your statement.  Just decided to provide the "syntactical sugar" function you referred to, in case someone was curious.